# Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'dotnetsmith.webcontrols.dll'

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have put the correct path for the dotnetsmith.webcontrols.dll.refresh in the full path column in the bin folder,yet it seems to be unable to find it and gives me the above error.

Comment: What error? Does the assembly show up with a yellow triangle symbol in the under `References`? Does your project have the same target framework as the referenced assembly?

Comment: @scheien Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'dotnetsmith.webcontrols.dll'.This is the error im getting. Yes it shows a yellow triangle under the warning tab. Yes for targetted framework

Comment: Have you added this through NuGet? Have you tried re-adding it?